# Where can I store private images for my app (outside of internal storage)?

Tags: android, file, local-storage, storage, android-contentprovider

**Is there a place where I can store and manage my own images outside of internal storage?** I don't want other apps to be able to see or access these images. Should I use external storage? Does such a place exist in the new `MediaStore`? It's fine if they're deleted when the app is deleted.

This solution needs to support API 21 or higher.

I know there are a lot of questions like this, but they're 10+ years old and a lot has changed since then.

**Use case / background**

I have an app where all data is stored locally on the device (no external servers).

Users can choose custom background images for journal entries. A user could choose to use a different image for each journal entry they create. They can create as many journal entries as they want. They may revisit those journal entries. So, I need to store an unknown amount of images for the lifetime of the app. I've been saving a copy of the images the user picks from the gallery in my local app storage via `context.filesDir`.

I noticed a crash `Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException disk I/O error (code 4874 SQLITE_IOERR_SHMSIZE)` and after googling, I found `This error may indicate that the underlying filesystem volume is out of space.`

My concern is that my app is running out of internal storage space because of the user images I'm storing.

Where should I be storing these images? I originally chose internal storage because I wanted my users' images to be reasonably private (since I don't know if they're storing sensitive images or not). I also wanted to make sure the images would always be available even if the source image (chosen from user's media) is deleted. However, I hadn't considered the limits imposed on internal storage. Silly me!

Comment: How would storing your images in a different directory have any effect on a user whose device ran out of space? That's out of your control.

Comment: How many images are you saving that is eating up device storage? consider only keeping the latest image for reference instead of creating a whole list of duplicate images on the device.

Comment: check out [official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)

Comment: @GavinWright Yes, device space is outside of my control, but this is about internal storage. All apps are allocated a dynamic & unknown amount of internal storage. Presumably, my app ran out of internal storage because I let users fill it up with an unknown amount of large picture files. Since databases are kept in internal storage by default & since my app has used up its allocation of internal storage, I'm getting crashes. If I'd used external storage, my app would still be able to perform DB operations and other functions (saving to shared preferences). That's a big difference.

Comment: @snachmsm The official doc doesn't mention a way to store images privately other than internal storage, which is what I'm asking about. If I use `MediaStore API` any other app can see the images.

Comment: @DarShan I'll update the question to be more clear. My use case lets the users add custom backgrounds for journal entries. A user could choose to use a different image for each journal entry they create. So, it's an unknown amount of images and every one of these images must be stored somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Android does not provide a place for you to store private photos (can't be accessed by user or other apps) outside of app's internal storage. I know you can contradict me by saying that one can store them in external storage by using `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` but the problem is that it is a shared directory accessible to users and other apps and remains when the app is deleted.

So I suggest you to use `getFilesDir()` as the directory returned by it is hidden from users and is deleted when the app is deleted. And also implement a image compressing tool in your app which automatically compresses images when uploaded by the user and then save it to internal storage. This won't solve the problem completely but I guess it's a start.

Answer (score 2):

Darshil's answer is correct. Using the recommended Storage Access Framework for your use case, you should use `getFilesDir()` which will return your app's internal storage, which is private to your app.

> Where should I be storing these images?

problem is due to limit of resource which is out of our control. However if you really want to store all the images, you can take some approaches:

**1. Online:** Use some cloud servers for storing user data. This might cost you a lot.

**2. Offline:** Tell user that you have only the limited amount of storage and storing more images will require to delete some older ones.

**3. Both:** Store in device. When internal storage is running low, tell user to buy some type of premium subscription to store unlimited cloud photos.

Answer (score -1):

With limited storage space appearing to be the root cause, I recommend intentionally using the UI to encourage users to use existing images over new images. (This can work in addition to the technical options provided in other answers)

For example, present the user with a list of available background images and a link to add a new image. In this case, using an existing image is 1 click with a preview, where getting a new image requires opening a new view and searching for the new image.

[image: Image Selection list and new image link wireframe]

Using the UI in this way doesn't directly get you more space, but it can help you to more efficiently use the space you have by guiding users to use existing images. It also gives you a place to warn about (or limit) adding more images when there is not more space available.

*If you still must have more storage on the device outside of the app, you could try using the public space with encryption for "privacy".

Comment: While this seems to be an honest attempt at solving the problem presented, it does not directly answer the question